# PHP: regular expression to remove bracket codes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to make a function to remove all the bracket codes but it doesn't seem to be working,

```
function anti_code($content)
{
    # find the matches and then remove them
    $output = preg_replace("/\[a-z\s+\]/is", "", $content);

    # return the result
    return $output;
}
```

I want these codes to be removed in the output,

```
Agro[space]terrorism
Agro[en space]terrorism
```

so that I can get

```
Agroterrorism
```

I must be something wrong in my regular expression! Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: as an aside, never use double quoted strings where single quoted ones will do, especially in regex patterns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You escaped the `[]`, but didn't add a second set of unescaped `[]` to designate a character class. Also, the `s` is not necessary if you're not using the `.` metacharacter in your regex.

Try this:

```
/\[[a-z\s]+\]/i
```

If you don't care what's between the square brackets and just want to remove everything contained in them, this will do:

```
/\[[^]]+\]/i
```

Comment: @ircmaxell: I'm trying to defy the constant connection reset errors that I'm actually getting right now, and showing my wi-fi router who's boss.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\[[a-z\s]+\]` It will capture brackets and  all contents

Comment: What would happen if you tried to match that against `foo[bar]baz[biz buz]`?

Comment: make it ungreedy `\\[.*?\\]` or just go with `preg_replace('/\\[(?>[^\\]]*)\\]/', '', $content);` less readable but the once-only subpattern makes it more efficient